# C macro processing

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm thinking about best way to write **C** define processor that would be able to handle macros. Unfortunately nothing intelligent comes to my mind.
It should behave exactly like one in **C**, so it handles expressions like this:

```
#define max(a, b) (a > b ? a : b)

 printf("%d\n", max(a, b));
```

Or this:

```
#define F 10
#define max(a, b) (a > b ? a : b)

 printf("%d\n", max(a, F));
```

I know about install and lookup functions from K&R2, what else do I need for
replacing text inside parenthesis?
Does anyone have any advice or some pseudo-code maybe?
I know it's complex task, but still, what would be best possible way to do it?

Comment: What's wrong with the built-in macro system in C? Or is this for some other application?

Comment: Why do you want to use this? Can you just use `gcc -E` to see the preprocessed output?

Comment: Absolutely nothing I just wont write simple version of the same as exercise, and have no idea how to handle arguments.

Comment: look how others solve this: http://www.cabaret.demon.co.uk/filepp/

Comment: Those macro definitions are lousy - use parentheses around each 'a' and 'b' in the replacement text.

Comment: Thanks guys, you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macro processors are very interesting but can became a difficult beast to tame (think about recursive expansions, for example).

You can look at the implementation of already existing macro processors like M4 (http://www.scs.stanford.edu/~reddy/links/gnu/m4.pdf).

In very general terms you will need:

- a parser that will first extract the macro definitions from your files (deleting them from the file, of course)
- another parser that identify where macros need to be expanded and performs the expansion (e.g. you will want to skip strings and comments!)

I think it's a very interesting exercise. The proper data structure to handle all this is not trivial.

Comment: <shameless>I do have an example of a very simple macro system in my c-libutl package. It doesn't do all that you need, but in case it might be useful you can find it here: http://code.google.com/p/c-libutl/source/browse/trunk/examples/macro/macro.c </shameless> :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pattern matching problem, you should take a look at [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to start with, then when you've grasped the theory on that you could move on to reading about [lexers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).

A regular expression is basically matching a string to a predefined pattern.

Some regexp (short for regular expression) software/libraries:
 - [Boost.Regexp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html)
 - [GNU C library regexp](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html)
 - [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/)

And a lexer is a piece of software that does something with the matched text, for example, replacing that piece of text with some other piece of text, basically what you seem to need.

Some known lexers:
 - [flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/)
 - [Boost.Wave](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/wave/index.html)

Comment: Anyone have suggestions to a pure C regexp library?

Answer (score -1):

2 suggestions:

- use boost wave (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/wave/index.html)
- use the preprocessor that comes with your compiler

ie "don't try this at home".

Comment: There's no C++ tag on this question, so Boost is not an appropriate suggestion.